# Why does printing a variable and function call together in this code give an error?

Tags: python

I've started learning Python through Zed Shaw's "Learn Python the hard way" [(link here)](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/)

In [this example](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex24.html) I changed the code snippet below:

```
def secret_formula(started):
    jelly_beans = started * 500
    jars = jelly_beans / 1000
    crates = jars / 100
    return jelly_beans, jars, crates


start_point = 10000
beans, jars, crates = secret_formula(start_point)

print "With a starting point of: %d" % start_point
print "We'd have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crates." % (beans, jars, crates)
```

to this:

```
def secret_formula(started):
    jelly_beans = started * 500
    jars = jelly_beans / 1000
    crates = jars / 100
    return jelly_beans, jars, crates


start_point = 10000
print "With a starting point of: %d we'd have %d, %d, %d" % (start_point,secret_formula(start_point))
```

Why does it give the error:

```
TypeError: float argument required, not tuple
```

when this line works fine?

```
print "We'd have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crates." % secret_formula(start_point)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `secret_formula()` returns a 3-tuple:

```
(jelly_beans, jars, crates)
```

So the original print statement:

```
print "With a starting point of: %d we'd have %d, %d, %d" % (start_point,secret_formula(start_point))
```

Becomes:

```
print "With a starting point of: %d we'd have %d, %d, %d" % (start_point, (jelly_beans, jars, crates))
```

The specific `TypeError` you are getting is because the tuple `(jelly_beans, jars, crates)` is the second argument which must be of format `%d` which indicates is a decimal integer. Tuples are not implicitly convertible into a int or float. I'm not entirely sure why it says a "float argument [is] required" instead of an integer one though.

Also note that the print statement contains 4 `%d`s so it expects 4 separate values. You gave it 2:

1. `start_point`.
2. `(jelly_beans, jars, crates)`.

The reason the second print statement works fine is because the `%` operator accepts either a single value, or multiple values packed into a tuple which `secret_formula()` happens to return.

Answer (score 2):

Since the return value of `secret_formula` is a tuple, when you write:

```
print "We'd have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crates." % secret_formula(start_point)
```

It becomes

```
print "We'd have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crates." % (1, 2, 3)
```

To make it work correctly in your example, you have two options:

1. Use the new [`.format()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples), with [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

   ```
   print "With a starting point of: {} we'd have {}, {}, {}".format(start_point,*secret_formula(start_point))
   ```
2. Make `start_point` into a tuple, then add it with the result of the function call:

   ```
   print "With a starting point of: %d we'd have %d, %d, %d" % ((start_point,)+secret_formula(start_point))
   ```

For simple readability, I'd go with option #1

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however it gives me a syntax error (Invalid syntax). Any idea why? I'm using Python 2.7.8

Comment: Unfortunately, the `*secret_formula(start_point)` doesn't work outside of argument lists (at least, it doesn't for me on Python 2.6.4). But we can use tuple concatenation here: `((start_point,) + secret_formula(start_point))`. We need the outer parentheses because `%` has higher precedence than `+`.

Comment: Yes, option #1 looks good; and we can use the star unpacking construction here since it's in the argument list of `format()`.

Comment: Update duly noted @BurhanKhalid. We can also use options like {: f} instead of simply {} to give better accuracy in division

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `*secret_formula(start_point)` construction suggested by Burhan Khalid doesn't work outside of argument lists. But we can use tuple concatenation:

```
def secret_formula(started):
    jelly_beans = started * 500
    jars = jelly_beans / 1000
    crates = jars / 100
    return jelly_beans, jars, crates


start_point = 10000

print "With a starting point of: %d we'd have %d, %d, %d" % ((start_point,) + secret_formula(start_point))
```

**output**

```
With a starting point of: 10000 we'd have 5000000, 5000, 50
```

`(start_point,)` creates a one element tuple, so we can add it to the tuple returned by `secret_formula()`. We need the outer parentheses because `%` has higher precedence than `+`.